# SQL Code to Tableau

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I'm very new to tableau, and would like to know how to convert this SQL  to tableau.

```
select  case when RD = 1 then 'RD' 
             else 
                case when Claim_FeatureStatus <> 'Re-opened' 
                          and subro_only = 0 
                          and SIU=0 
                          then 'Open' 
                     when Claim_FeatureStatus = 'Re-opened' 
                          and subro_only = 0  
                          and SIU = 0 
                          then 'Re-Opened'
                     when SIU = 1 
                          then 'SIU'
                     else 'Subrogation'
                end              
          end as ClaimStatus
```

Comment: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/editing-custom-sql

Answer (score 1):

Tableau has a similar CASE function, but I'd recommend using the IF function to replicate this logic.

[image]

Hope this serves you well.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your question you are looking to utilize the dataset returned by this sql query for analytics in Tableau.

Here is what needs to be done - 
1) Connect to this SQL DB and create a datasource using 'custom sql' option
2) Go to your sheet and start visualizing this data

However your query is not complete so above will be difficult to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can write out whole sql queries and then build a report off of it in Tableau. Just connect to SQL server, put in credentials, afterwards there will be a "draggable" text to the side where it shows your tables called "Custom SQL Query" and you can paste that query right into it. Just drag that "Custom SQL Query" text over to the middle of the screen and it will let you.

To add to that you can then join other tables to that query by dragging tables needed to the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement or if-else statements. [Here is a really good resource](https://interworks.com/blog/tmcconnell/2015/02/10/case-statements-vs-if-statements-tableau) which compares and contrasts the two. Hope this helps in making your decision!